# сравнить хешированный пароль при регистрации

Tags: php, хеширование, соль

Здравствуйте! как сравнить пароль, точнее вывести то что в бд уже хешированный, показываю  на примере так пароль попппдает в бд

```
$password           =     ($_POST["password"]);

$iterations = 1000;

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);
```

потом пытаюсь авторизоваться и ни как не пойму как получить что нужно хеш выдает каждый раз что то новое авторизовываюсь

```
$password           =     ($_POST["password"]);

$iterations = 1000;

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);
$myrow['password'] === $hash// тут не правильно сравнивает
```

с md5 все работало но тут не пойму

Comment: рас с md5 работало зачем вам sha256 понадобился?

Comment: прочитал стать md5 и sha1 устарели есть еще билиотека  password compat , но мой хостер её не поодерживает, я думаю проблема с солью

Comment: password_compat, а точнее ircmaxell/password_compat - реализация нескольких функций PHP5.5 для старых версий PHP. Это не библиотека, чтобы её поддерживал хостер, а несколько обычных php-файлов с обычными функциями. Для php5.5 и новее вообще не нужна, соответствующие функции доступны нативно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Зачем вы при верификации пароля генерируете новую соль? Вы должны вместе с хэшом пароля сохранить сгенерированную соль и использовать её вновь при верификации. В этом случае получаемый хэш будет совпадать.

---

Обращаю внимание, что `mcrypt` [официально объявлен устаревшим](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php), уже PHP7.1 кидает E_DEPRECATED, в будущих версиях расширение будет выброшено в отдельный pecl-пакет и поддерживать его никто не обещает.

А для хранения паролей PHP начиная с версии 5.5 (и пользовательская реализация аж начиная с 5.3.7) [предоставляет нативные функции](http://php.net/manual/en/book.password.php), инкапсулирующие в себя необходимые криптографически-безопасные детали. Лучше использовать их.

Comment: то есть соль тоже хранить в бд?

Comment: Да, обычно рядом с паролем сохраняется. Функции password_hash упаковывают все необходимые для проверки данные (алгоритм, хэш, соль) в одну результирующую строку, поэтому password_verify продолжит работать и после изменения алгоритма хэширования в более позднем времени.

Answer (score 0):

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Може посмотреть видео, чтобы разобраться как правильно работать с паролями или задать вопрос в ЛС https://youtu.be/ZoazIUfbkQE

Comment: Ответы-ссылки не приветствуются. Но вообще видео нормальное.